# R Markdown - Object of dataframe not found even though object is in Global Environment pane

Tags: r, object, r-markdown, syntax-error

I am trying to create a R Markdown file.

In the environment pane, my dataframe is names "crimes".

In the code chunk area, I've tried View(crimes) and I consistently receive this error:

Error in summary(crimes) : object 'crimes' not found.
Calls:  ...withVisible -> eval_with_user_hanlders -> eval -> eval -> summary
Execution halted

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX29x.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEBjX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udsbu.png)

I am expecting to see a tibble of my data. It works in the console area, but not in R Markdown.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Objects in your global environment are not available when you knit an Rmd. When you knit an Rmd file it is "run" or rendered in a fresh R session, i.e. you have to load your dataset inside the Rmd.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Rstudio, from what I can see.  Have you saved session history by any chance? Did you reload the session?